# how to handle properly list of TextEditingController for a five TextFormField generated by the loop used by listview.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, texteditingcontroller

I'm having a future list to work with the listview.builder. I have another list

```
 List<QuizQuestion> listofquizquestionsforquiz=GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions;
```

for `listofquizquestionsforquiz` I want  every item in the list of TextEditingController to handle  the corresponding TextFormField, meaning for controllers[0] I want it to be attached and work with the first TextFormField the Listview.builder generates, then the second textedintingcontroller to the second textformfield ...
When I try to print `controllers[index].text`  I'm having no value printed. What can I do in order to make the controllers work one by one for this TextFormField ?

```
class AnswerQuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const AnswerQuizPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnswerQuizPage> createState() => _AnswerQuizPageState();
}

class _AnswerQuizPageState extends State<AnswerQuizPage> {
  int? _numPages ;
  int _currentPage = 1;
  bool test=false;
  bool colorchoice=false;
  var questionController= QuestionController(QuestionRepositoryImpl());
  List<String> reponse=[];
  List<String> asnwers=[];
  List<TextEditingController>_reponse=[];
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
  List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
  List<QuestionModel> listofquestion=[];
  List<QuizQuestion> listofquizquestionsforquiz=GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions;
  @override
  List<dynamic> trList=[];
  GlobalKey<FormState> globalFormKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
  void show(){
    List<TextEditingController> _controllers2=[];
    String test;
    GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.forEach((element) { final   quantityController =
    TextEditingController(text: element.userAnswer);
    controllers.add(quantityController);
    reponse.add(element.userAnswer);
    });
  }
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
//show();
    setState(() {
      if (GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.isNotEmpty) {
        controllers = GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions.map((s) {
          return TextEditingController(text: s.userAnswer);
        }).toList();
      } else {
        controllers = [];
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    Future<List<QuestionModel>> quizlist=questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id);
    quizlist.then((value)  {
      listofquestion=value;
    });
    _numPages=listofquestion.length;
    int? idtochoose;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        title:Text('répondre au quiz'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          //login
          Container(

            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              //color: Colors.orange[600],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, top:5.0, bottom: 5.0,),
            child: Tooltip(
              message: "vous devez finir le quiz",
              child: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            ),
          ),


        ],

      ),
      body: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<QuestionModel>>(
    future:questionController.getQuestionsByQuizId(GlobalParams.quizmodel.id),
    builder:(context ,snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting){
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
    }
    if (snapshot.hasError){
    print('${snapshot.error}');
    print('${snapshot}');

    return Center(child: Text('${snapshot}'),);
    }
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: buildBodyContent(snapshot, questionController)),
       /* QuizQuestionTextControllerWidget(controllers: _controllers, listofquizquestions: GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions, reponse: reponse),*/
        SizedBox(height: 50,),
        Container(
          child: FormHelper.submitButton("Ajouter", () async{
            print('hello');
            print('${GlobalParams.quizmodel.id}');
            print('${GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions[0].quizquestionpk.idQuestion}');
            List<String> textList = controllers.map((x) => x.text).toList();

            for (var j=0;j<textList.length;j++){
              print(j);
              print(textList[j]);
            }
      },
            btnColor: Colors.blue,
            borderColor: Colors.white,
            txtColor: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: 10,),
        ),
      ],
    );

    },
    ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

SafeArea buildBodyContent (AsyncSnapshot <List<QuestionModel>> snapshot,
    QuestionController questionController){
  bool colorchoice=false;
  Color colorDet;
 List <String> reponse=[];
  List<String> asnwers=[];
 List<QuizQuestion> listofquizquestions=GlobalParams.quizmodel.quizQuestions;
 List<TextEditingController> controllers=[];
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
 int idx;
  return SafeArea(
    child:
    Scrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      thickness: 5,
     // scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context,index)
          { var cq=snapshot.data?[index];
            controllers.add( TextEditingController());
            return Column(
              children:[
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(cq!.enonce, style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse a : ${cq.propositionA}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse b : ${cq.propositionB}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Text(
                        'réponse c : ${cq.propositionC}', style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                      Container(
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            colorchoice=!colorchoice;
                            if(colorchoice){
                              colorDet = Colors.green;
                            }
                            else {
                              colorDet= Colors.orange;
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'réponse d : ${cq.propositionD}', style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                            controller: controllers[index],
                            //onEditingComplete: (text) {  print('First text field: $text');  },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: ' réponse',
                            ),
                            validator: (value){
                              if (value!.isNotEmpty){
                                // _controllers.add(_controllers[index]);
                                print('${controllers[index].text}');

                                //asnwers.add(asnwers[index]);
                                // tr="QUATRE_A_CINQ";
                                return null;
                              } else {
                                return "libelle ne peut pas être vide";
                              }
                            },
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              onFieldSubmitted: (value){
                              print(value);
                              },
                      ),
                          ],
                        ),
                   /* })
                  ],
                ),*/
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
              ],
            );
          },
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ??0),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution it might work for you.

Replace this

```
controllers.add(TextEditingController());
```

with

```
controllers.clear();
snapshot.data?.forEach((element) {
              controllers.add(TextEditingController());
            });
```

Comment: thank you for you help but it still did not work

Comment: can you please share your small code snippet.

Comment: I basically made the adjustments you suggested, still got the same issue, I think I need to have the TextFormField in a separate stateful widget in order to make it work, this is what I'm trying right now, if you want I can share it with you

Comment: Just print what is the length of your controller list and snapshot.data length if both match then there no need to take stateful widget.

Other solution is take whole widget in your AnswerQuizPage.
It should work according to me.

Comment: I tried that now I'm having the error of the list of controllers being empty 
Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: I'm getting your issue can't do more until the exact error.
Because i'm not sure in which line you are getting error.